# Creating events in Google Calendar so that the details are kept private

Tags: google-calendar

I am using Google Calendar to making appointments and keep track of them. Is there a way to create an event and then make it so people can see that there is an event on that day, but they can't click it and see the info about that event? If not, are there any programs out there that can do this?

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried this yet but I will thank you

Answer (score 2):

When [sharing the calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en), choose the option that allows others to

> #### See free/busy information (no details)
>
> See when your calendar is booked and when it has free time, but not the names or other details of your events.